# Embedded Apache Artemis with Quarkus

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, microservices, quarkus, activemq-artemis

I am looking to run Artemis in an embedded mode in my service. I am looking to see what gradle dependency to add this purpose. I followed the instructions on the document below

https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.0.0/embedding-activemq.html

but not sure which gradle dependency to include to get the EmbeddedActiveMQ class/library. I tried the below

implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-artemis-core'

in my build.gradle file but i get an exception the class not found despite the dependency being loaded (gradle build doesn't throw any error). Any idea what is missing?

Thank you in advance!

SG

Answer (score 0):

The latest documentation for [Embedding Apache ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/embedding-activemq.html) is https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/embedding-activemq.html

The `quarkus-artemis-core` artifact from [Quarkus Artemis](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-artemis) is for the Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Core *client* not the *server*.

See the [embedded](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/2.27.0/examples/features/standard/embedded) or [embedded-simple](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/2.27.0/examples/features/standard/embedded-simple) examples to figure out the dependencies required to [embed Apache ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/embedding-activemq.html).

For gradle:

```
implementation 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-server:2.27.0'
```

For maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>artemis-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.27.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you Dominico for the response. Will checkout the links provided. I am also looking for the plug-in to use with Gradle which i can't seem to find on the links. Is it Artemis-server?

Comment: Yes, you need the artemis-server dependency. The examples are based on maven, to add the artemis-server dependency in a gradle project you can use the following line: `implementation 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-server:2.27.0'`